# Sonarqube create a webhook programmatically

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube, webhooks

Is there any way to create a webhook in sonarqube without the panel administration? I want to launch a sonarqube docker and create automatically a webhook pointing to jenkins instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `api/webhooks/create` web service (requires admin perms). You'll find a link to web service docs in the footer of your instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right: https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/webhooks.

Here it is the code:

```
 curl "http://admin:admin@sonarqube:9000/api/webhooks/create" -X POST -d 
 "name=jenkins&url=http://jenkins:8080/sonarqube-webhook/"
```

Comment: I get: {"errors":[{"msg":"Unknown url : /api/webhooks/create"}]}.